# Get the correlation between one variable and all the rest of the dataset

Tags: python, correlation

If you want to get the correlation between all the variables in a dataframe you can just do:

```
c = df_train.corr().abs()

s = c.unstack()
so = s.sort_values(kind="quicksort")

print(so)
```

However, in this case I have 90 variables, plus I already know my dependent variable ("sales").
How can I get the ordered correlation values between "sales" and the rest of the variables.

Comment: Are you asking because you just want to select the correlations involving `sales` or are you asking because you want to prevent `pandas` from even computing the correlations you don't need (for performance reasons for example)? For the former, you can just select the `sales` series from the `.corr()` result - for the latter, you probably want [`corrwith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html#pandas.DataFrame.corrwith)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking because you just want to select the correlations involving `sales` or are you asking because you want to prevent `pandas` from even computing the correlations you don't need (for performance reasons for example)? For the former, you can just select the `sales` series from the `.corr()` result - for the latter, you probably want [`corrwith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html#pandas.DataFrame.corrwith)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'name': 'john', 'age': 21, 'beard_len': 3, 'wrinkle_index': .02},
    {'name': 'pete', 'age': 83, 'beard_len': 21, 'wrinkle_index': .87},
    {'name': 'will', 'age': 54, 'beard_len': 13, 'wrinkle_index': .52},
    {'name': 'mike', 'age': 32, 'beard_len': 11, 'wrinkle_index': .24},
    {'name': 'greg', 'age': 61, 'beard_len': 14, 'wrinkle_index': .49},
])

print(df.corr()['age'])
print(df.corrwith(df['age']))
```

Output:

```
age              1.000000
beard_len        0.951520
wrinkle_index    0.986042
Name: age, dtype: float64
age              1.000000
beard_len        0.951520
wrinkle_index    0.986042
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Once you have every correlation you can filter those involving the variable "sales"

```
sales_correlations = so.sales
```

### Option 2

Get the correlation of the whole dataframe with the "sales" series

```
c = df_train.corrwith(df_train.sales)
```